# vbscript how do I import a function without that function running automatically?

Tags: syntax, vbscript, structure

I have two vbscript files, file1.vbs and file2.vbs
In a.vbs, I have the following code:

dim a : a = 1

```
function myFunction(k)
...
end function

call myFunction(a)
```

So file1.vbs can actually run standalone. Now in file2.vbs, I want to call myFunction(k) that resides in file1.vbs. However, when I import file1.vbs in file2.vbs, the calling myFunction is also imported, resulted in running myFunction automatically with parameter "a"... This is not what I want, because I might give a different parameter to myFunction, say "b".

How should I structure the program such that file1.vbs can run standalone, while file2.vbs can also call myFunction in file1.vbs but with different input parameter? Thanks.

Comment: How are you importing `file1.vbs` into `file2.vbs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way, in my opinion, would be to have library/module `.vbs` files containing only reusable subs/functions/classes but no top level (immediately executed) code. User `.vbs` files import libraries via [ExecuteGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1%28v=VS.84%29.aspx) on `.ReadAll()` as shown in this [Microsoft TechNet post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/e5b50398-d12a-4e93-ae33-d3929228eddb).

(Also see [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2%28v=vs.84%29) which has similar functionality but can also define objects and variables that have *local* scope.)

If you insist on mixing module and top level code, you can use a Pythonic idiom and compare the current `WScript.ScriptName` against a string literal and call the appropriate 'top level code' only when they match.

Comment: Ekkehard @Horner - happy to pitch in. Wonder if we'll hear back from the poster... (BTW, when I place the (at) in front of Ekkehard, it does not stick.)